# Laravel multi auth | Route middleware

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, routes

I have to tables which i am authenticating with `users`, `admins`.
I have changed the config/auth.php accordingly for guards and providers.

Now i have some guarded routes for `admins` like :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('adminIndex');
});
```

I am applying `middleware auth` on the above route, It kicks me back to the `user` login page(`/login`), Not to the admin dashboard page.

Why is that, What am i missing ?

Comment: show your middleware??

Comment: It's funny I wrote an article on access control just two days ago https://www.kerneldev.com/2018/02/12/set-up-role-based-access-control-in-laravel/  You might want to check it out :)

Comment: can you show your middleware

Comment: @sohel0415 The middleware `auth` is the built-in middleware of laravel. I haven't wrote it !

Comment: @sibasankarBhoi The middleware auth is the built-in middleware of laravel. I haven't wrote it !

Comment: @SapneshNaik I have two tables not one where i can place a field of role.

Comment: If you are using the built-in middleware then you're seeing the built-in behaviour.

Comment: @apokryfos i know, Is there any way around it ?

Comment: The built-in middleware accepts the guards as parameters so if you have a custom guard use `auth:customguardname` instead of just `auth` unless your custom guard is also the default one

Comment: @apokryfos ! Okay Now when i want to go to admin login its redirects me to the users login page !

Comment: In the default laravel exception handler (App/Exceptions/Handler.php) there's an `unauthenticated` function which is the default redirect. It accepts an `AuthenticationException` which itself includes the guard it failed on so you can modify that code to redirect according to the guard. https://laravel.io/forum/09-01-2016-laravel-53-auth-redirect-guests-based-on-guard has some useful info

Answer (score 0):

You Should mention the guards name along with the middleware.if you have an admin guards then define like below.

**Please Try this, hope it will work**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function () {
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('adminIndex');
});
```

Comment: Done ! Now when i want to go to admin `login` its redirects me to the users login page !

Comment: Please see this github repo. i think it will help your problem.. https://github.com/rahmanmajeed/MultiAuthDev